# File template C++ Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2012, comments

Is it possible in Visual Studio, when creating a new file, producing automatically something like this:

```
// <filename>.<ext>
//   Author: <name>
//   Update: <date>
```

I'm currently working with C++ projects, and this would be very helpfull!

EDIT:

Using Visual Assist X should be fine! I'll update
**Yes, I will definitely use Visual Assist X!**

Comment: Though I've not done so myself, I would think a simple [Visual Studio Add-In](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80493a3w(v=vs.110).aspx) would make something like this fairly simple, if not already done for you by MS and one of their multitude of add-ins.

Comment: so are you manually going to change the date everytime you change something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a file like you show to an existsing project, then use `File->Export Template...` and select the file you just created. It will create a template for you, and by editing the files in the zip it you can get pretty close. Not sure if you can get the date right though.

Alternatively you can create a snippet for it, but that's less extensible.

Finally as WhozCraig suggested: creating Add-Ins is not too hard and gives you total control.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing I've seen in the settings options but why not have a empty C++ file with that already stored that you just add to your project, if I find anything I'll update this.